# joranConfigurator doing multiple tasks

Tags: java, jboss, logback

I have a project where logback uses joranConfigurator to get a system variable in a startup bean, but I also want to tell it to parse an XML file with the logback configuration AFTER it has already gotten the variable set up... I cant rely on using the standard logback.xml name because the way the project is set up I have to do it this way

heres my current code:

```
private void configureLogBack() {

        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

        try {
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
            configurator.setContext(context);
            // Call context.reset() to clear any previous configuration, e.g.
// default
            // configuration. For multi-step configuration, omit calling
// context.reset().
            // context.reset();
            configurator.doConfigure(System.getenv("logPath"));
        } catch (JoranException je) {
            // StatusPrinter will handle this
        }
        StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(context);

    }
```

do I do `context.reset()` then do another `configurator.doConfigure()`? and what do I pass in as the argument, the name of the xml file???

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new method that had the same setup but passed the doConfigure() method the path and name of the xml file i wanted parsed. Also uncomment the context.reset() and run both methods.